# How can i position this divs?

Tags: css, html, position, css-float

i got 5 divs and 4 of them got:

```
4divs{width:150px; height:100px; float:left;}
```

and the mid div:

```
midDiv{width:200px; height:200px; float:left;}
```

and the container:

```
container{width:500px; height:200px;}
```

what i want is:

[image]

Comment: can you modify the html structure? or only using css?

Comment: do you know css ? just check for your floats

Comment: those divs are actually posts so i cant rly modify the html

Comment: and how you are posting them ? maybe in a sequence .. <div><div><midDiv><div><div>

Comment: thats it <div><div><midDiv><div><div>

Comment: You need `jQuery` and http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: get Firebug: https://getfirebug.com/
So that you can see html and css of that site.

Comment: Also right-click on those dives and click `inspect element` to see the css and html in Firefox or google chrome.In Firefox click `style after that to view it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `#container{position:relative;}` and than for each of your divs give absolute positioning:

```
div:nth-child(1){position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
div:nth-child(2){position:absolute; top:100px; left:0;}
div:nth-child(3){position:absolute; top:0; left:100px;}
div:nth-child(4){position:absolute; top:0; right:0;}
div:nth-child(5){position:absolute; top:100px; right:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

assume the names: div1, div2, div3, div4 and div-mid.
Try arranging like this...

`<container>`

`<div1> </div1>`

`<div-mid> </div-mid>`

`<div2> </div2>`

`<div3> </div3>`

`<div4> </div4>`

`</container>`

Then you will

- position div3 to extreme left *in* the container.
- position div4 to extreme right *in* the container.
- Then position them both at bottom *in* the container.

Try `float: left` and `float : right` for that.
Try doing `position: relative` for div3 and div4.

And if you don't have, get Firebug: 
https://getfirebug.com/

Comment: By the way <pre> </pre> is not working with that code so I had to write this weird way.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot achieve what you want from the given state of your CSS for the Divs. No matter what you do, you have to modify the specified CSS in order to achieve that.

There are two possible ways you can go about it

1. place three divs floated left or displayed inline i.e. next to each other in a horizontal line. Then divide the left and right divs into two parts vertically i.e.

   ```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left">
         <div class="upper"> 
         </div>
         <div class="lower"> 
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="middle">
     </div>
     <div class="right">
        <div class="upper"> 
        </div>
        <div class="lower"> 
        </div>
    </div>
   ```
2. make your divs `position:absolute`

see this [fiddle for 1st solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ULmzb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to create that layout with just css given your current html structure.

You'd really need to have the following html structure which means one container with three floating dics with your individual blocks inside them.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="container-2">
        <div class="div1">
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-2">
        <div class="div2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-2">
        <div class="div1">
        </div>
        <div class="div1">
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- / .container -->


.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container-2 {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.div1 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.div2 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 210px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container-2 .div1:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```